# In a OrientDB query, how can the where clause reference a column in the select

Tags: orientdb

I want to write a query in OrientDB performs WHERE filtering on some columns/fields on the SELECTed vertex.

Here is the equivalent query implemented with nested SELECT's-

```
SELECT FROM (SELECT EXPAND(OUT('Foo')) FROM  #13:1 )  WHERE prop = 'bar'
```

How I can write this query with a single SELECT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
create class Foo extends E

create vertex                                  #9:0
create vertex set prop = 'bar'                 #9:1
create vertex set prop = 'baz'                 #9:2

create edge Foo from #9:0 to #9:1
create edge Foo from #9:0 to #9:2
```

You can:

```
select expand(out('Foo')[prop = 'bar']) from #9:0
```